# Have the review audits got cranked up again?

Tags: support, review-audits

Not intended as a complaint, but it looks like there are "continuously" adjustments made to the review system - I noticed a higher frequency lately - Just now I got 2 audits for 8 reviews in "suggested edits" - seems to be a rather high percentage.

So I'd suggest reducing the frequency a bit again.

Comment: Their frequency is completely random, you just picked a bad day ;-)